# "lest" in your daily life

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Today I heard the word "lest" in our daily chat with some teammates and I even thought it was a typo.

As far as I understand, it means 'avoiding', but can I use it normally in my daily speaking ?

I read some examples, but none of them from daily life:

["lest" examples](https://lengusa.com/search/lest)

> Large shell collections are built up by exchanging duplicates with other collectors. Hence it is wise to take a number of specimens. A notebook should be carried in which records may be made at the time of collecting, lest important data be forgotten.

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary?

Comment: Sure, that's why  I said it means kinda 'avoiding'. It just sounded off to me, and that's why I asked is it okay to use it in our daily life.

>With the intention of preventing (something undesirable); to avoid the risk of.

Comment: "Lest" is relatively formal and can sound old-fashioned - it is usually accompanied by the subjunctive. Its use in Standard BE has been declining. MW (AE) has " for fear that —often used after an expression denoting fear or apprehension [e.g. *"I am] worried lest she should be late."* *"[He was] hesitant to speak out lest he be fired.*

Comment: _Lest something happen = so that it doesn't happen_. As Greybeard says, it's a bit formal for everyday conversation.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, can you please elaborate the part 'subjunctive' ? Not sure I get it clearly.

Comment: @Greybeard Please use the Answer Box.